# The case when x == !x return true in javascript

Tags: javascript, compare, equals

When a string contains only blank char (eg: space,tab,newline char), `x == !x` returns `true`.

Example:

```
"\t\n\r" == !"\t\n\r" // true
```

This is because when compare with `==`, string with only blank char is converted to `0`,
but for `!`, `"\t\n\r"` is considered as a non empty string, so `!"\t\n\r"` is `false`,
`0 == false` returns true.

The question is, is this the only case (*string with only blank char*) when `x == !x` returns true?
Any other examples?

---

Inspired by @Ted Hopp's answer:

**Every string except empty string `""` which could converted to 0 make `x == !x` stands.**

Example:

```
"0.0" == !"0.0"
"608E-4234" == !"608E-4234"
```

Comment: `[""] == ![""]; // true` The `!` converts the truthy Array object to `false`, and the first `[""]` will be converted to string `""`, and `"" == false` is `true` via the eventual numeric conversion.

Comment: Same will work with `[0] == ![0]`

Comment: Or this: `[[]] == ![[]]` Doesn't matter how deeply nested, as long as the `.toString()` of the left array results in a value that will be eventually converted to 0. `[[[[[0]]]]] == ![[[[[0]]]]]`

Comment: `null` in the arrays works too

Answer (score 4):

This is also `true`:

```
"0" == !"0"
```

Other cases would be similar — any non-empty string that evaluates to 0 when coerced to an `int` would work for `x == !x`.

Comment: Yes, every string except empty string `""` which could casted to `0`.

Comment: @xdazz - Right. I see you added a couple of interesting examples.

Comment: What's weird is that while `x == !x;` is true, still this is true: `(x ? true : false)` and this is false: `(!x ? true : false)`  when `x = "0"`.  Doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @SebastiánGrignoli - A large part of the problem is that, in a boolean context, `"0"` evaluates to `true`; in a numeric context, `"0"` evaluates to `0`; and in a boolean context `0` evaluates to `false`. (Likewise, `false` becomes `0` in a numeric context.) The behavior of `==` is defined by the [Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3) specified in the standard. If you work your way through that, you'll find that `"0"` is converted both to a boolean value and then to a number and also directly to a number, hence the inconsistency.

Answer (score 0):

This is also true

```
" " == !" "
```

even `" "` could casted to 0

Comment: That's one of the cases OP originally mentioned.